# Complement of family of binary sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider set of the binary sequence, we choose an element $(0,0,0,...)$,then construct a family of sequence by changing each entry, so that each element is different from zero vector by one entry. Denote the elements by $x_{n}$. Now we proceed the similar way, from starting on the element of this family, changing each entries to construct new family of sequence. Denote the elements by $x_{nm}$, constructed from $x_{n}$. We then do the same for all elements we have, producing $x_{nmi...}$. Finally taking union of all the elements, denote it by $X$. What is the complement of $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base 0-th step gives all sequence with at most zero nonzero values values.
The 1st step gives all sequences with at most 1 nonzero value.
The n-th step gives all sequences with at most n nonzero value.
Altogether all the steps yield all sequences with a finite number of nonzero values.
The complement is now apparent.

Comment: so the complement is the sequence with infinite number of zero entries?

Comment: @Ken.Wong The negation of a finite number nonzero values is an infinite number of nonzero values.